# How can I get the enemies to move?

Tags: c++, opengl, programming-languages

Hello I am trying to get enemies to move left and right as if they are sliding backwards and forwards I know this can be done with the following code:

```
slide += slide_incr;                            
if(abs(slide)>30) slide_incr = -slide_incr;
```

However this is of no use to me as I need to set a boolean so I can cycle through the frames for when the enemy is going right or going left.

Ive tried the follow code with no luck:

```
if(abs(eSlide)<=0)
{
      eSlide += eSlide_incr;    
}

if(abs(eSlide)>30) 
{
      eSlide_incr = -eSlide_incr;   

}
```

Any ideas on how I can implement it?
Thanks

Comment: You might get some better answers at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: realize that `abs(eSlide) <= 0` is equivalent to `eSlide == 0`...

Answer (score 1):

You want to hold a hysteresis state for if you're sliding forward or backward. You are also mixing up how to use the `abs()` function when bounds checking. Try something along the lines of:

```
eSlide += eSlide_incr;
if (abs(eSlide) >= 30) {
    eSlide_incr = -eSlide_incr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the first thing that stands out for me is that the contents of the block:

```
if (abs(eSlid) <= 0) {
    eSlide += eSlide_incr;
}
```

will never ever run (the absolute value will always be greater than or equal to 0)

as for your boolean facing, that can be achieved with:

```
bool isSlidingRight = eSlide_incr > 0;
```

(note: this would still use the left animation set for values of 0)